# Parallelizing multiple for loops with mpi4py and/or multiprocessing?

Tags: parallel-processing, python-multiprocessing, slurm, hpc, mpi4py

I am trying to run a function with multiple arguments within multiple for loops on a HPC cluster via SLURM with python:

```
def (x,y,z):
    return(np.zeros((x,y,z)))

first_loop = 20
second_loop = 4
third_loop = 3

result = {}
for i in range(first_loop):
    for j in range(second_loop):
        for k in range(third_loop):
            result['%d,%d,%d'%(i,j,k)] = f(i,j,k)
```

This takes forever for my actual function. So, I use `multiprocessing` to speed things up:

```
result = {}
for i in range(first_loop):
    inputs_ = []
    for j in range(second_loop):
        for k in range(third_loop):
            one_set = (i,j,k)
            inputs_.append(one_set)

    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes = 12) as pool:
        r = pool.starmap(f, inputs_)

    for j in range(second_loop):
        for k in range(third_loop):
            result['%d,%d,%d'%(i,j,k)] = r[int(j*len(third_loop)+k)]
```

where my SLURM script has:

```
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=12
```

i.e., I am using 12 CPUs on a single node to distribute the tasks. I do this 20 times repeatedly. But this is still not good enough.

I am limited by the number of CPUs on a node, and I can't get 240 CPUs on a single node. So my question is, how do I distribute this job into 20 different nodes each utilizing 12 CPUs?

Is the answer `mpi4py`? If so, can someone help me how to set it up? Is it doable via only `multiprocessing`?

Thank you

Comment: `multiprocessing` cannot be used for distributed computing. It is only useful on 1 node. If you want to use more nodes, then `mpi4py` is a good option. Note that `mpi4py` is certainly better on 1 (shared-memory) node than `multiprocessing`. Besides using `mpi4py` should be simple here since the problem is apparently embarrassingly parallel. That being said, you should really optimize `f` before using several HPC nodes (otherwise it would waste a lot of resources -- sometimes this is even required by the HPC machine admins).

Comment: Regarding the use of `mpi4py`, there are several tutorials including the [official one](https://mpi4py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html) and even books about this. This should be enough for this simple use-case.

Comment: Okay, sounds good. I think the key word was `embarrassingly parallel'. Thank you!